# How to query the sum of all digits in a given number?

Tags: sql, oracle

Can I query the sum of all digits in a given number value?

Example of the input value:

```
  EMPNO 
  -----  
  7369
```

I want to get this as a result:

```
 7+3+6+9 = 25
```

I thought about this solution, but I don't think it's efficient:

```
SELECT SUBSTR('12345',1,1) + SUBSTR('12345',2,1)
FROM DUAL;
```

Comment: is there an upper bound for the size of the value?

Comment: Yes, you can. Convert Empno to string, go through the collection of chars, convert every single char into number and sum it. But i doubt you need it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the solution:

## 1. Simple Query

```
SELECT id,sum(SUBSTR(empno, LEVEL, 1 )) sums
FROM   (select 1 as id, 7369 as empno from DUAL)
      CONNECT BY LEVEL <= LENGTH(empno)
group by id
```

## 2. Using CROSS JOIN

```
SELECT sum(column_value)
FROM   (
  SELECT 7369 val,
         ROWNUM AS id
  FROM dual
) t
CROSS JOIN
TABLE(
  CAST(
    MULTISET(
      SELECT SUBSTR( t.val, LEVEL, 1 )
      FROM   DUAL
      CONNECT BY LEVEL <= LENGTH( t.val )
    )
    AS SYS.ODCIVARCHAR2LIST
  )
) c
```

Output:

```
SUM(COLUMN_VALUE)
25
```

Comment: Check out the answer, if the information is useful to you can vote up and mark it answered.

Comment: Pardon me again. The `id` column  in the first  select is not required unless you want to `order by` But , yes if its a column in the table.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not fluent in oracle SQL, but this is an approach without converting to string (which will be faster). Basically do a mod + division operation to get each different number, and add them.

```
DECLARE testNumber integer := 123

SELECT
    testNumber,
    MOD(testNumber, POWER(10, 1)) +
        MOD(testNumber, POWER(10, 2)) / POWER(10, 1) +
        MOD(testNumber, POWER(10, 3)) / POWER(10, 2) +
        MOD(testNumber, POWER(10, 4)) / POWER(10, 3) +
        MOD(testNumber, POWER(10, 5)) / POWER(10, 4) +
        MOD(testNumber, POWER(10, 6)) / POWER(10, 5) +
        MOD(testNumber, POWER(10, 7)) / POWER(10, 6)
FROM
    DUAL
```

Will have to keep add sums up to the max amount of positions you might get.

Answer (score 1):

One more approach, using `XMLTABLE`

```
WITH t (s)
AS (
    SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(7369, '(\d)', ',\1') 
    FROM DUAL
    )
SELECT sum(to_number(column_value))
FROM t
    ,xmltable(0||s)
```

[**Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/e0ee9e/862)

Or, a pure PL/SQL based solution using mod operation.

```
DECLARE 
    n INTEGER := 2562337328382; 
    s INTEGER := 0; 
BEGIN 
    WHILE n > 0 LOOP 
        s := s + MOD(n, 10); 
        n := floor(n / 10); 
    END LOOP; 
    dbms_output.put_line(s); 
END; 
/ 
54
```

Answer (score 0):

Query for dynamic values.

```
Declare @Num varchar(max)='54666', @Len int=1,@Total int=0
while @Len<=LEN(@Num)
begin
Set @Total=@Total+CONVERT(int,substring(@Num,@Len,1))
Set @Len=@len+1
end
select @Total
```

Just change the `@Num` value and try.